# How should I setup orthographic projection to fit multiple screen sizes

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine, glm-math, orthographic

I am currently trying to setup orthographic projection for a game in OpenGL, but I struggle a bit with setting it up correctly.

Currently I am calculating my projection using this simple function:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, width, height, 0.0f, -10000.0f, 10000.0f);
```

where width and height are given by the screen size.

This leads however to a few problems, namely the objects on screen get stretched or compressed when I change the size of the screen. And when the screen size gets bigger more of the current Scene is shown.

What I want is that I always see the same thing on screen independent from the size of the window, but it should also not distort if I resize the window to some weird aspect ratio.

I tried a few things like using the aspect ration, but I either didn't see anything on screen or things were even worse distorted.

Here is also my model and view matrix code in case I have done something wrong with that:

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(TransformComponent.position.x+width/2 /*width and height are needed to place the object in the center of the screen*/, TransformComponent.position.y+height/2, TransformComponent.position.z));
model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(renderable.GetWidth(), renderable.GetHeight(), 1.0f));
sh.setMat4("model", model);
ViewMatrix

glm::mat4 transform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(position,0)) *
glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(0.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));

glm::mat4 m_ViewMatrix = glm::inverse(transform);
```

Small screen

[image: Small screen]

Big screen

[image: Big screen]

Distorted screen

[image: Distorted screen]

Another distorted example

[image: Another distorted example]

Answer (score 0):

The math scales the projection centered on resize. If you're using resolution to scale the 2D objects centered, the original offset positions it to be centered on 1:1 ratio.

```
srcaspect = 4f / 3f;
dstaspect = width / height;
orthosize = (dstaspect < 16f / 9f ? dstaspect : 16f / 9f) / (16f / 9f);
centerscalex = 0.5f*(height - 0);
centerscaley = 0.5f*(height - 0);
centeroffsetx = (scalex + 0) * srcaspect;
centeroffsety = scaley + 0;
```

then throw all that in the matrix using this formula, and vola, you get a centered aspect display:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(centeroffsetx - (centerscalex * dstaspect * orthosize),centeroffsetx + (centerscalex * dstaspect * orthosize),centeroffsety - (centerscaley * orthosize),centeroffsety + (centerscaley * orthosize));
```

I'd recommend you'd use a default height, if you don't want the object to shrink on bigger resolutions, like this:

```
centerscalex = 0.5f*(480f - 0);
centerscaley = 0.5f*(480f - 0);
centeroffsetx = scalex + 0;
centeroffsety = scaley + 0;
```